# Error while scraping website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some songs from genius. I created the following method:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    def get_song_lyrics(link):
    
        response = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        lyrics = soup.find("div",attrs={'class':'lyrics'}).find("p").get_text()
        return [i for i in lyrics.splitlines()]
```

I don't understand why this

```
get_song_lyrics('https://genius.com/Kanye-west-black-skinhead-lyrics')
```

returns:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

while this:

```
get_song_lyrics('https://genius.com/Kanye-west-hold-my-liquor-lyrics')
```

returns correctly the lyric of the song. Both pages have the same layout.
Can someone help me figuring that out?

Answer (score 2):

The page is returning two versions of HTML. You can use this script to take care of both of them:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://genius.com/Kanye-west-black-skinhead-lyrics'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')

for tag in soup.select('div[class^="Lyrics__Container"], .song_body-lyrics p'):

    for i in tag.select('i'):
        i.unwrap()
    tag.smooth()

    t = tag.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')
    if t:
        print(t)
```

Prints:

```
[Produced By Daft Punk & Kanye West]
[Verse 1]
For my theme song (Black)
My leather black jeans on (Black)
My by-any-means on

...and so on.
```

Comment: Is it random which version it is returning?

Comment: @7koFnMiP Yes, it seems it's some form of anti-bot protection.

Comment: how did you find out that the page was returning two versions of HTML?

Comment: @Porridge I put `print(soup)` inside `try..except` and searched, what tags were missing. Sometimes the script ran ok, but sometimes, the tags were completely different.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is causing it, but it looks like sometimes `BeautifulSoup` is successful and sometimes not, and not due to your code. One workaround would be running the function again if the code isn't successful:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_song_lyrics(link):
    
    response = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    try:
        lyrics = soup.find("div",attrs={'class':'lyrics'}).find("p").get_text()
        return [i for i in lyrics.splitlines()] 
    except AttributeError:
        return get_song_lyrics(link)
    
get_song_lyrics('https://genius.com/Kanye-west-black-skinhead-lyrics')
```